# How to partially color section title without changing the displayed title in pdf?

Tags: pdftex, color, bookmarks

Hi I would like to do something like this to my section title

[image]

It seems doable but it gives

[image]

on the PDF file bookmarks. Is there a way to remedy this? I have set the default color of the section title to be blue, so the code is as follows

```
Edu\color{black}{cation}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `\color{black}` is nothing the bookmarks understand!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give an alternative with `\texorpdfstring{Edu\color{black}cation}{Education}`.

And please notice that `\color{black}` does not take any additional arguments, if you want that syntax, use `\textcolor{black}{bla}`

Comment: Not really necessary here, but on occasion, it might be better to use `{\color{blue}Edu}cation` or `\textcolor{blue}{Edu}cation`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer But as "section title to be blue", one would first have to change the default colour...

Comment: Well, I doubt that the default colour is blue at all... And I meant the grouping of `{\color{}...}` rather.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer From the text I assume it's probably some kind of CV template, so I would not rule out that blue is it's default colour for section headings. Grouping: That's the handy thing in colouring the renaming string in black, as the heading is inside it's own group, there is no danger that the colour spill out :)

Comment: Yes, I know. My comment was meant for the case that Blue isn't the default colour.

Comment: thanks! I wonder if we can do this more generally? Like defaulting my section title to always be this style, without having to go through this every time?

Comment: @ChesterCheng: That's another question.

Comment: @ChesterCheng For an automatic solution, look into the source code of http://www.latextemplates.com/template/friggeri-resume-cv